# Angular - Proper way to call procedure after async call to backend

Tags: angular

i have a bit of situation with executing procedure after async call to backend api

```
this.includedServicesList.forEach(x =>
          this.ccApi.getServicePrice(x.ServiceCode, '0', 'NONE')
            .subscribe(data => {
              x.ServicePrice = data.MPrice;
              this.includedServicesPrice += data.MPrice;
              //this.calculatePrices();
            })
        );
        //this.calculatePrices();
```

For each element of array I need to call backend api (get some data from database).

After that is done I would like to call calculatePrices procedure to update data. If I put procedure call after forEach loop, it just gets executed before data is even gathered.
If I put it inside subscribe block, it gets called once for each element in array (and I need it called only once after entire loop is done)

Is there any good way to solve this (without setting random timeouts and hoping all async calls will be done by that point or stuff like that)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip) operator.

> After all observables emit, emit values as an array

```
import { zip } from 'rxjs';

zip(
   this.includedServicesList.map(x =>
      this.ccApi.getServicePrice(x.ServiceCode, '0', 'NONE')
         .pipe(tap(data => {
            x.ServicePrice = data.MPrice;
            this.includedServicesPrice += data.MPrice;
         }))
   )
).subscribe(()=>this.calculatePrices())
```

the part

```
data => {
            x.ServicePrice = data.MPrice;
            this.includedServicesPrice += data.MPrice;
         }
```

Would be called after **each** response received. `calculatePrices` would be called when **all** the responses received.

Comment: Thank you, but my project has rxjs version 5.5.6. Can you help me how to use it on that version? I realised I have to change import to import { zip } from 'rxjs/operators'; but have no idea how to write other part

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a playground to test it. 
I think `import { zip, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';`, copy the first code sample from the answer and substitute the code sample from the question.
does it work?

Comment: Not really, sintax seems to be different for these versions. But nevermind, I managed to solve this problem in a different way, backend is sending data in earlier step so don't need this working on older version. Thank you for solution, good to know for future needs ;)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this work, because I cant see your backend call, but maybe you can provide instead of just one element to your service function, the entire array. Your serivce function then handles an entire array and returns then an array of prices, so you just have to make one call and dont have to wait for all the other calls. I hope you get what I mean. If not let me know!

Comment: Thank you, yes, I got what u are saying. But I'm using existing function that is used on other places of the same app (since I'm working only on small part of it), so changing backend is not much of an option in this case. I could add new function that would behave like that but this is only use, adding additional method for this seems bit much

Comment: Do you call your forEach Loop in ngOnInit?